# Creation of a Mini-Pluggable Architecture with a "Plugin Registry" using Type Initialization, Concurrent Access, and Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have need for some basic "pluggable" architecture, and was curious if my assumptions and idea for an implementation are as I believe they are. The basic process for setting up a "Plugin Registry" containing all classes supporting some functionality is as follows:

1. Reflect over the classes in the assembly and find any of them
   inheriting from a Plugin base class.
2. Generate a new "ModulePlugin" object storing a name from the class name and grabbing a reference to the derived type, and potentially grabbing some meta information like a "Plugin Type" from an attribute.
3. The plugin type above will create a new instance of the derived type upon request, but return it as a Plugin base class in the "ModulePlugin" object above.
4. Store the generated plugins in a List

In step four I am doing this with a static class "PluginRegistry" with a static type initializer and storing the generated data structures (List < Plugin>) in a static readonly IEnumerable< Plugin>.

Throughout the application I use the plugins in this fashion:

```
PluginRegistry.Plugins.Where(plugin => plugin.Type == Logger).Foo();
```

This is in an ASP.NET MVC application. 
I am assuming:

1. Type initializers/constructors are safe to use in this
   fashion where concurrent access occurs (ASP.NET)
2. That the reflection required will only run once for a
   given App Pool Life-cycle and more precisely not over and over again
   for each request as this is a static class using type
   initialization.

I have a functioning prototype, but I am worried about unforeseen problems.

Are my assumptions correct, and are there any gotchas I should be aware of?

Comment: Programmers.SE might be a better forum for this type of q.  I do not see any glaring issues with your design at first glance.

Comment: Creating a custom plugin manager can be interesting as an exercise, but otherwise, it's just reinventing the [wheel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx).

Comment: MEF is overkill for something like this. I'd rather not force new developers to learn a new framework when the core of the same thing can be done with a targeted support class of 30 lines or less. I'm also not sure MEF would fit the constraints of the environment I am in. Sometimes the existing wheels just aren't a good fit for the cart you have.

Comment: this has been done and not once. before mvvm and all that hype. nothing is wrong with it. quite often light-weight DIY plugins beat all the 'patterns' and 'frameworks'..... the problem Joshua is that this is done when you know what you do and what for. if you are asking like that you probably dont need to bother with